# c# need to raise event when in scope of LOCK

Tags: c#, events, locking

I have a filehandler class that moves an xdoument to cache using a lock.
 Psuedo code:

```
public FetchDocument() {
    var xdoc = Cache[_Key1];
    if (xdoc == null) {
        lock(_lockobject) {
            // in case prev.thread has done upload will currth read waiting
            xdoc = Cache[_Key1];

            if (xdoc == null) {
               .... Code to grab from file and add to catch - works great.....
            }
        }
    }
    xdoc = Cache[_Key1];

}
```

Now I want to expose and event that fires after the file has been loaded but before its cached and which has an abort flag on the event.

The problem is how do I only fire the event(s) for the Current (unlocked) thread only?

an other thread may be locked waiting for this thread to clear the locking code

Thanks

Martin

Comment: It is considered bad practice to fire events from inside of a locked context, as it can easily lead to deadlocks.  For more explanation, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932108/c-invoke-event-from-locked-block

Comment: I can't understand your exact problem, but your code has a bug,in current thread `xdoc == null` and in the other thread you are out of `lock` block and you going to do `xdoc = Cache[_Key1];` but in current thread you going to add item to catch and may be you doing some extra work or exception occure.

Comment: Seems like a spectacular amount of effort to prevent having to load a file twice.  Which is generally trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you wish to allow the caller to abort caching the document. You can achieve this by passing a Func into your FetchDocument method, e.g.:

```
public XDocument FetchDocument(FUnc<XDocument, bool> cacheNewDocument) {
    var xdoc;        
    lock(_lockobject) {
        // in case prev.thread has done upload will currth read waiting
        xdoc = Cache[_Key1];

        if (xdoc == null) {
           xdoc = .... Code to grab from file and add to catch - works great.....

           if (cacheNewDocument(xdoc)){
               Cache.Add(_Key1, xdoc)
           }
           else{
               return xdoc;
           }
        }
    }

    return xdoc;
}
```

In this way your code can call the Func with relevant data before adding the document to the cache and the caller can return true\false to get your abort semantics.

This is much more straightforward than using an event, and enforces the "how do I only fire the event(s) for the Current (unlocked) thread only" semantics.

On another note, although your original code is pseudo code, you are accessing the Cache object outside the lock. Even though these unlocked operations are read operations, the collection could be being mutated inside the lock and so you could get unpredictable results. All operations on the cache should be done in the lock.

Comment: like that solution - just have to pass func through if needed thanks

Comment: @user442348 If this solves your issue, please remember to vote me up and accept this as the answer. There is a voting system on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Why the downvote on 29/11/2010. Someone seems to have tracked through a whole bunch of my questions and down voted. Not nice.

Comment: +1 - read the answer, seemed like a good answer, not sure why you were downvoted.  Odd.

Comment: @Matt Cheers for the up-vote. Basically I down-voted an answer (on some unrelated question) on the '29/11/2010' and that user systematically went through all my previous answers that were accepted but had 0 votes and down-voted all of them so I ended up with a bunch of accepted answers with "-1" votes. They were just being vindictive - it was quite annoying at the time. There's no recourse for that sort of behaviour on SO unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

All events are processed by the current thread, the problem arises if any of your eventhandlers tries to invoke the UI thread or take another lock.
In that case [`Monitor.TryEnter`](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=monitor.tryenter) might help in those event handlers.

But the best would be to break up your lock into two locks, one before and one after the event.